# Libgdx degree between two points calculation

Tags: rotation, libgdx, formula, points, degrees

Here I am calculating degree between actor and touch point and passing this degree to actor as rotation angle.I want the actor should point towards the finger touch or finger dragging direction.(consider i am pulling bus on road by finger touch and drag )

```
float degrees = (float) ((Math.atan2(touchPoint.x - crocodile.position.x, -(touchPoint.y - crocodile.position.y)) * 180.0d / Math.PI));
```

Its calculating degree properly. only sometimes in between it is giving bit different degree. so my actor is fluctuating when result is really different than expected.

result that i printed is :

> Blockquote

```
    degree is :: 141.93233
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 158.61426
    degree is :: 90.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 90.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 141.93057
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 141.93306
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 141.93257
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 141.93134
    degree is :: 141.93257
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 141.93134
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 141.93306
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 141.93257
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 141.93134
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 141.93257
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 141.93257
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 141.93134
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 141.93257
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 141.93008
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 141.93306
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 141.93257
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 141.93134
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
    degree is :: 180.0
```

Now , 180 and 141 why it is fluctuating with those values.
considering i am expecting 141 constantly or 180 constantly what i need to change in above formula.

Comment: It cannot change as long as your input doesn't change (assuming you have a deterministic cpu, which should be the case...). So either your touchpoint changes, or your crocodile's position.

Furthermore: something like `touchPoint.sub(crocodile.position).angle()` is probably much more easy to understand?

Comment: @noone , I think by using 

`code` 
touchPoint.sub(crocodile.position).angle()

i can find angle right ?
but crocodile.position is Vector2 value and sub is not taking Vector2 value and if i am using 

`code` touchPoint.sub(crocodile.position.x,crocodile.position.y,0).angle();

then also it doesn't match with any API doc function. means angle() is not resolving there....


in above answer  

"you said your crocodile's position changing "YES " i want to tell you that yes i am updating the crocodiles position to the touch-point."

then what can i do if I want to move it there..

thanks.

Comment: `Vector3` has no angle(), but `Vector2` does. So try something like `flot angle = (new Vector2(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)).sub(crocodile.position).angle()`.

Comment: @noone , I am getting same effect of fluctuation by your solution also.. the issue is I am doing..
`code`
crocodile.position.x = touchPoint.x ;
crocodile.position.y = touchPoint.y ; 

that might be the issue...
I have to resolve it but however i have to move the crocodile ..

Comment: If you change the positions, the angle will always change, so that's not a problem. I just offered the other implementation because it is much easier to understand.

Answer (score 5):

First parameter must be y and the second is x.

```
double atan2(double y, double x)
```

Atan2 is actually specified arctangent function of y/x

Because of that usually first parameter is taken y.

Also you can get proper degree sometimes when you swap x and y because in some borders like x<0 and y<0 it doesn't matter swapped or not.

[Look here for more explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation)

Comment: Please [format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your answer to improve its readability.

Answer (score 2):

Combining the question and the answer helped me solve my problem quickly. Just to clarify the solution a little:

```
double degrees = Math.atan2(
    towards.getY() - pointer.getY(),
    towards.getX() - pointer.getX()
) * 180.0d / Math.PI;
pointer.setRotation((float) degrees);
```

Also note that in order to rotate around the middle you need to do:

```
pointer.setOrigin(Align.center);
```